# mysql filesystem

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to create a file system like this. Whenever a new user is registered a folder with unique ID is created for storing images in the filesystem for that user. If he/she creates a new album for pictures another new folder will be created inside that unique folder for the user.
Thank U.

Comment: This really isn't the place to ask questions like this.  Give it your best shot, and come to us when you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with server-side scripting. For example, with php you can create a new directory using the `mkdir()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 0):

Beware of scalability issues. I'd recommend you to add another level if indirection, that is, to store user directory in the table. At first you may create directory structure however you like, but when you'll have tens of thousands of directories at one level of filesystem, you could get into filesystem-level performance issues. Then you'll just reorganize your folders, move files, and update table links.